# Connect to Derby using IKVM, C#

Tags: derby

I used IKVM (ikvm-7.2.4630.5) to convert derby-10.11.1.1.jar and derbyclient-10.11.1.1.jar to dll and add reference to my project.

I want to write an C# app that connect to Derby database and get data.

Here is code (work well with Java)

```
 DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver());
 Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:C:/sampleDb;create=true");
```

But it throw exception at line 1. See error.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in app.exe
>
> Additional information: The type initializer for
>   'org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver' threw an exception.

How to solve it or another way to get data from it?

Comment: I don't think a conversion like this is possible. I think embedded Derby runs only in Java. Did you read somewhere that a translation like this is possible?

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/derbynet/. I found this but this dll not working with me.

Comment: I think you must contact the author of that package. I have never seen this  project discussed among the Derby developers community and I suspect any guidance will be **very** specific to that implementation.